# ATI Driver and settings change

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ati

I have the need to programmatically change the various settings that are present in the ATI Catalyst control center.

From AMD website I downloaded ADL SDK, which seemed to allow me to change the settings for under and over scaling, resolution, frequency and brightness.

However, it seems I'm not able to change the settings in the video section with my program: for example if I try to change screen brightness, changes are not propagated or applied, resulting in screen not changing the brightness.

The operating system of choice is Windows 7. 
Is ADL the correct technology to do that and how can I change this setting?

Comment: For your program or for every program on the system?

Comment: For every program on the system, in the video overlay specifically